# JavaScript - AJAX / 'Data' is empty / asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I found some similar questions but none of them resolve my problem.

The problem I have is that my data from my AJAX-call is empty but my controller return exactly I want him to return.

I tried to add a `contentType`, but neither `contentType` nor `ContentType` worked for me.

What am I doing wrong?

JavaScript:

```
function AddFunction() {
var ergebnis = "";
var zahl1 = $("#txt_1").val();
var zahl2 = $("#txt_2").val();

$.ajax({
    async: false, 
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Calc/Add',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        'val_1': zahl1,
        'val_2': zahl2
    },
    success: function (data) {
        ergebnis = data.result;
        alert(ergebnis);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Fehler");
    }
});
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Add(string val_1, string val_2)
{

     string sUri = "http://192.168.111.173:35145/temppath/GVCalc/1.0/add";
     var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUri);
     httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
     httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

     using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
     {
         string json = "{\"field_1\":\"" + val_1 + "\"," +
                          "\"field_2\":\"" + val_2 + "\"}";

         streamWriter.Write(json);
         streamWriter.Flush();
         streamWriter.Close();
     }

     var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

     var result = DeserializeFromStream(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
     return Json(result);
 }
```

Controller result:

> {{
>     "result": 3
>   }}

Ajax data:

> kinda empty / no result at all

**Edit:**

DeserializeFromStream Method:

```
public static object DeserializeFromStream(Stream stream)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use "data" and not "data.result" for the result. See if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I checked `data` with the debugger. But i tried it and it is still empty.

Comment: can you try this ? return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

Comment: Did not throw an error but unfortunately data is still empty

Comment: @YiğitYüksel why would adding AllowGet help when the ajax call is doing a POST?

Comment: @R.Pülsinger what data type does DeserializeFromStream return? (i.e. what is the data type of `result`)?

Comment: I edited my Post, i added the DeserializeFromStream-Method. It returns an object.

Comment: hmm. Just try changing `dataType: 'JSON',` to `dataType: 'json'`, not sure if it's case-sensitive. And when you get the response, check for any console errors. And check in the network tab to see what the response looks like in there, see if it contains any data of any sort.

Comment: lul. i had the same idea 15 minutes ago. did not work, seems like its not case-sensitive or both are wrong. I added a `ToString()` to the result (at return)  and now i get `"{\r\n  \"result\": 3\r\n}"` in the data object of ajax

Comment: what does `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by sending a string and parse it in JavaScript. This worked fine for me :)

C#:

```
return Json(result.ToString());
```

JavaScript:

```
var ergebnis_json = JSON.parse(data)
ergebnis = ergebnis_json.result;
$("#ergebnis").val(ergebnis);
```

Thanks everyone for their help :)